# jstree not working on IE9

Tags: javascript, tree

JStree is not working properly with IE9. You can check this in their demo page [here](http://www.jstree.com/demo). Trying internally, nodes can not be collapsed/expanded and the whole tree is expanded after load. Some hint on this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution, change the IE mode in the header (switch off quirk mode) :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

It's working for IE8 and IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Add cache field:

```
'data': {
    "url": 'YourUrl',
    "data": { yourparameter},
    "cache":false // <- added
}
```